# Where is root directory in Tomcat web application?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, tomcat8

I have a web application using Tomcat whose index.jsp needs to read some data from a textfile.
However, I'm not quite sure as to where the root directory is.

Can anybody give me any insight, material, and/or solutions as to where this directory is and how it is decided that it must be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CATALINA_HOME is Tomcat directory. Look at folder `%CATALINA_HOME%\work\Catalina\localhost\web_application_name\` or
`%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\ROOT`

Comment: Great, it was in `%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\ROOT`. I appreciate your assistance.